# How does c++ cout know which system call to use to connect to standard io streams

Tags: c++, operating-system

Basically, cout is defined in iostream header which is part of c++.I want to know how does this take into account the OS dependent system call interface?

Comment: Those are Implementation details... You would have to be more specific about which implementation you're asking. GCC, Clang or MSVC etc.

Comment: The C and C++ Runtime Support libraries have to be ported to each supported platform.  Part of the porting is to change all the system calls to be correct for that platform.

Comment: @Richard Critten does this mean that the source code of iostream header would vary according to the OS?

Comment: headers specify interface, not implementation.

Comment: @stark Templates laugh at that ideal.

Comment: Take opening a file, on MS-Windows the native API is `CreateFileW` on Unix like system it will be different.  So if you trace `std::fopen` down through the implementation layers you would come to the native call.  Whether this is conditionally compiled or not depends on if the tool-chain vendor supports multiple platforms.

Comment: @Dumb_Pegasus Yes it does. It will likely vary according to the compiler as well.

Comment: @Dumb_Pegasus: In theory contents of iostream header could vary according to the OS; but in practice an (portable) implementation likely uses the exact same "layers of fluff" for every OS where the only thing that's system specific is a final low level `write()` system call underneath all the layers.

Comment: Right, thanks Richard, John and Brendan. This explains it